# How to solve proivder error in SQL Server database connection string (ASP.NET)

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, ms-access, dropdownlistview

I am trying to create a dropdown list from a table in my database and I get the error:

> Keyword not supported: 'provider'

I want to generate a dropdown list which will contain the cities in the table cities in my database and will return the index of each city in it.

`connect.cs` class

```
namespace RapidTyper.App_Code
{
    public class connect
    {
        const string FILE_NAME = "DataBaseR1.accdb";

        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            string location = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + FILE_NAME);
            string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" + location;
            return ConnectionString;
        }

        public connect()
        {
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        }

        public static void writeline()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList   ID="ddlSubject" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="<Select Subject>" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
        LoadSubjects();
}

private void LoadSubjects()
{
    DataTable cities = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cityNum, cityName FROM cities", con);
            adapter.Fill(cities);

            ddlSubject.DataSource = cities;
            ddlSubject.DataTextField = "cityName";
            ddlSubject.DataValueField = "cityNum";
            ddlSubject.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two significant issues here.

First up: You are using the SQL provider.

SQL provider is only for SQL Server. It not for Oracle, not for MySQL, not for PostgresSQL and of course not for MS Access.

So, you have two choices here for which provider to use:

You can use ODBC, or you can use OleDB.

I am going to suggest OleDB, but you MUST swap out the `SqlProvider` for Access.

So, assuming a imports `System.Data.OleDB` ?

Then all of the "base" data objects are still the same - but the provider(s) have to be changed. So say this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect.GetConnectionString()))
{
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT cityNum, cityName FROM cities", con);
```

becomes:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbCommand(connect.GetConnectionString()))
{
    try
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT cityNum, cityName FROM cities", con);
```

Ok, so as noted, you can swap out the `SqlProvider` (for SQL Server) and use OleDB, or you can use OleDB. your connection string looks to be OleDB.

Next up:

Is the web site running as x32 bits, or x64 bits? The bit size of your .net application MUST match the bit size of the external "un-managed" code - in this case the Access database engine "ACE".

You can thus change the web site to run as x32 for testing here:

[image]

And you ALSO must set your project to run as x32 here:

[image]

So the .net project must be changed from "any" or x64 and MUST be x32.

You then have to set/ensure the web site launches as x32 (as per first screen cap).

And MORE important, while you can make the above two changes to run as x32? These days, MOST often the web site when deployed will be running as x64 bits. So this quite much suggests that you need to download and install a x64 bit ACE database driver - as the x32 bit one can't be used with a site running as x64 bits.

In summary:

- You are trying to use the `SqlProvider` here - that is for SQL Server ONLY.
- You need to swap out the provider - use OleDB one, or ODBC - either one can work.

OleDB provider string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\test\test44.accdb
```

ODBC provider string

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
dbq=C:\test\test44.accdb;defaultdir=C:\test;driverid=25;
;maxbuffersize=2048;maxscanrows=8;pagetimeout=5;safetransactions=0;threads=3;
 uid=admin;usercommitsync=Yes
```

You could likely shorten the odbc string to just the driver and path as per above.

You have to deal with the bit size. During development and testing, you can set your project to x86 (any CPU will NOT work!!!!). But if you set to x86, then you have to set the web server to also run as x86. If you looking to use x64 in final deployment? Then I would force everything back to x64, and install the x64 bit version of the ACE database engine.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to write: using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbCommand(connect.GetConnectionString()))
{
    try
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT cityNum, cityName FROM cities", con);"

as you said but now i am getting the error :

cannot implicitly convert type 'system.Data.oleDb.oldeDbcommand ' to system.Data.oleDb.oldDbconnection'

Comment: i have changed it to : 
    '    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connect.GetConnectionString()))  '
and now it's working. 
Thanks.